# scipy solve with unknowns in both vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, solver

I'm currently trying to implement a finite element method in Python and I have to solve a linear system where the matrix is under determined, but the system should be well-defined by the boundary condition.

To be precise, in a very simple case, the matrix looks like this

```
[ 12.,   6., -12.,   6.],
[  6.,   4.,  -6.,   2.],
[-12.,  -6.,  12.,  -6.],
[  6.,   2.,  -6.,   4.]]
```

And the right-hand side is just an array of numbers.

Obviously, the third column is the negative of the first, so the matrix is under determined.

However, I want to impose that the first entry in the solution vector is zero, so the solution should be of the form `[0,x,y,z]`. Now we have 3 unknowns and 3 equations, so there should be a unique solution, but I haven't found a scipy function that does that, since the normal scipy.linalg.solve only takes the matrix and the right-hand side as inputs.

I've tried to rewrite the linear system, but in some cases there are undefined variables in the right-hand side as well and more set values in the unknown vector, so I'm looking for a procedure that solves an any linear system with the matrix, and two vectors with unknowns.

Comment: Please give examples of the remaining vectors as well.

Comment: Is the left-hand side always 4x4? Is the solution vector always 1x4? Please write out all matrix dimensions and the actual form of the matrix equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem Statement

You're question is a bit confusing because your matrix has rank 2 and not 3 (this means it gives you only 2 linearly independent equations). Now if I call your matrix `A` and the right hand side `b` the best you can hope for is a solution of the form

```
A@[0,0,x,y]=b.
```

Keep in mind that this does not always work. Indeed since the last two columns of A are linearly independent this solution exists if and only if `b` is in the image of `A`. So `b` must come from some multiplication of `A` with a vector.

### Linear Algebra Idea

Now if we remember one simple fact from linear algebra we can find you a solution in the form you hope for. We can write any solution `x` to an underdetermined linear equation as `x=v+n` with `v` being any solution and `n` being from the null space of the matrix. So we just find a solution that is not in the form yet and then bring it into the form by moving it threw the null space of `A`.

### Example

Let's go thew an explicit example: suppose we have

```
b=[12,4,-12,8](=A@[1,2,3,4]).
```

(Of course I assume here we don't know that `b=A@[1,2,3,4]`.)
We can find a solution with `v=np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0](=[ 0.4, -0.8, -0.4,  1.2])`. Here we should double check that `A@v==b` (or at least that `np.isclose(A@v,b)`) since `np.linalg.lstsq` does not throw an exception if no solution exists but gives you an approximate one.

If now you want a different solution in your special form you just calculate the null space

```
null_space = scipy.linalg.null_space(A)
```

and then how we have to change `v` to get it to be zero in the first two entries

```
coefs = np.linalg.solve(null_space[:2], v[:2])
w = -null_space@coefs
x = v+w.
```

Turns out `x=[0,0,0,2].`